# Will a study gap of 3 years harm my chances of getting admission to a graduate program in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have completed my undergraduate in 2018 with a CGPA of 3.86/4.00 and have not enrolled in an MS course. This is because I have decided to gain some research experience. And also the current pandemic has affected heavily my decision on the MS study.

However, in the last three years, I have been involved in numerous research projects and published 14 research articles, attended 16 conferences with 10 conference abstracts, I have worked with multiple volunteering organizations, and also gained professional experience of about 1 year in a company.

Now, my question is, will this **STUDY-GAP** of 3 years harm my chances of getting admission into a PhD program or an MS (research-based) program?

In the US, one can apply directly to PhD after Bachelor's degree.

I need your suggestions. Thanks...

Comment: No, if anything such a gap should strengthen your application. Admissions committees like to know that you'll stay the course, and people who aren't coming straight from undergrad tend to have a better perspective on what they want to do and hence commitment to the PhD. On top of that, you haven't just "wasted" that time, but done very successful research by the sounds of it.

Comment: I know people who did their PhDs in their 40s and 50s (and got permanent academic jobs afterwards).